# apache url rewrite for multilanguage site

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to achieve two goals using rewrite conditions under apache2 but this is not actually my cup of tea:

- redirect mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com and this is pretty easy to do. I use:

  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
- redirect mydomain.es to www.mydomain.com/?lang=es (and so on for different languages)

How can I write the second statement? And how can I combine this rule with the first one?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+) %{HTTP_HOST}$1 [C]
RewriteRule ^mydomain\.([^.]+)/(.*) http://www.mydomain.com/?lang=$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It's Ok for mydomain.es, mydomain.fr, mydomain.pt but it's no OK for **www**.mydomain.es

Comment: sorry for late response but I just had the opportunity to test it.